# How to make DuckDuckGo.com use a font with spaces in its name in Safari?

Tags: font, safari

DuckDuckGo.com makes it easy to define your own display font.

It works well, except for fonts with a space in their name, like "IBM Plex Sans".
I tried "quotes", escaped%20punctuation, adding the style like Regular, but no luck.

Help!

PS: I don't want a style override extension or GreaseMonkey script, just to use the existing feature.

PPS: This is an issue only in Safari on macOS; on Chrome, the features works as expected and looks awesome.

[image: Screenshot of DuckDuckGo settings widget in Safari on macOS]

Comment: I posted this question previously but it got closed, because _"the question does not appear to be about web applications within the scope defined in the help center."_ The link https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says _"If your question generally covers […] *Google* or any other website which behaves like an application […] … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_
FFS, why is Google worthy but DuckDuckGo no?! Why @Rubén ?!

Comment: I already explained on the original site the reason of the migration rejection. In first place "bad questions" should not be migrated. The original question doesn't included enough details , and this post has the same problem. Anyway, in my case the default font name has a space in the name (Proxima Nova) and it looks to be working fine. Have you already reviewed the DuckDuckgo help resources to check what fonts are supported? What make you think that the IBM Plex Sans font is supported ? Have you tried other fonts? What is the name and version of the OS and web browser that you are using?

Comment: Have you already reviewed the web browser console?

Comment: The feature seems to work well in Chrome but not Safari.  
After some more trials and error, I still could not find a solution.

Comment: I have an idea of what is happening but might not be relevant for you specific circumstances. Please [edit] the question to add the previously asked details

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional details, but I think that you might need to be more specific. I tested this issue using Chrome on a Mac Mini (M1); setting IBM Plex Sans font didn't work for me but another font installed in the local fonts folder worked fine. What macOS version are you using? Does the Safari console shows any message?